# Why does Class.forName() not work for me?

Tags: java, class, instantiation, classname

I'm trying to instantiate a class from variable, and wrote some test code. But, unfortunately, it isn't working. Here is the code:

```
Object co1 = new CommandDownloadHttp();
Class cc1 = Class.forName("CommandDownloadHttp");
Object co = cc1.newInstance();
```

Unfortunately on second line it crashes with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is CommandDownloadHttp the *full* name of the class, i.e. it doesn't have a package? If it *does* have a package, include that:

```
Class.forName("foo.bar.CommandDownloadHttp");
```

(I assume there's a better reason for you doing this in your real code, btw - clearly in this case you don't actually need to fetch the class by reflection :)

Comment: replace namespace w/ package (to be me java centric). I realize they're sorta the same concept.

Comment: Thank you! :)

Yes, these lines is only example. In real life name will be constructed on execution.

Answer (score 3):

Is your class in a package? And this package is imported? So it works in line 1. But you need the full qualified name in Class.forName("my.package.to.CommandDownloadHttp").

Comment: Thank you for answer. I didn't thought about package.